# C#. В чем разница между вложенными namespace и namespace, составное имя которых включает в себя точки

Tags: c#, namespace

Здравствуйте!

Есть 2 файла:

1. Nesting.cs:

   ```
   namespace Demo
   {
       namespace NestingNS
       {
           class Nesting
           {
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. NoNesting.cs

   ```
   namespace Demo.NoNestingNS
   {
       class NoNesting
       {
       }
   }
   ```

В первом файле пространства имен вложены друг в друга, во втором - пространство имен имеет составной идентификатор (если его так можно назвать).

**Вопрос 1**: В чем разница между данными объявлениями (кроме названий классов и пространств имен)? Или 2-ой случай - это некое подобие синтаксического сахара, которое разворачивается в 1-ый случай?

**Вопрос 2**: В каких случаях лучше использовать первое объявление и в каких второе?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это синтаксический сахар. Если вы пишете очень большую программу или библиотеку вы можете хотеть чтобы ваш проект описывало пространство Security, но так, чтобы пользователь знал что оно лежит в System.
Чтобы сохранить удобную иерархию, чтобы пользователь (другой программист) мог даже без документации посмотреть какие разделы есть в вашей библиотеке.

Answer (score 5):

1. Прямой разницы нету. Но для случая «вложенного» объявления вы можете завершить вложенное пространство имён раньше, и начать новое пространство имён:

   ```
   namespace A
   {
       namespace B1
       {
           class С1 {}
       }
       namespace B2
       {
           class С2 {}
       }
   }
   ```

   Кроме того, для случая «вложенного» объявления вы можете вставить дополнительный `using` внутрь, что даёт интересные эффекты:

   ```
   using System;

   namespace A
   {
       using Console = Tools.Console;
       namespace B
       {
           class Program
           {
               static void Main(string[] args)
               {
                   Console.WriteLine();
               }
           }
       }
   }

   namespace Tools
   {
       class Console
       {
           static public void WriteLine() => global::System.Console.WriteLine("Снаружи");
       }
   }
   ```

   Это вызовет `Tools.Console.WriteLine` вместо `System.Console.WriteLine`.

   Отличие от помещённого `using Console = Tools.Console;` на промежуточном уровне и на внутреннем проявляются в случае, если внутри `B` есть свой класс `Console`: для кода

   ```
   using System;

   namespace A
   {
       using Console = Tools.Console;
       namespace B
       {
           class Program
           {
               static void Main(string[] args)
               {
                   Console.WriteLine();
               }
           }
           class Console
           {
               static public void WriteLine() => global::System.Console.WriteLine("Внутри");
           }
       }
   }

   namespace Tools
   {
       class Console
       {
           static public void WriteLine() => global::System.Console.WriteLine("Снаружи");
       }
   }
   ```

   будет выведено «Внутри», а не «Снаружи».
2. Это вопрос вкуса. Я бы использовал, если возможно, более короткое объявление, чтобы не загромождать текст программы.

Comment: Очень четкий ответ! Даже и спросить нечего, все понятно стало!
Большое спасибо Вам за подробный ответ. Вы не обидитесь, если я лучший ответ отдам более молодому члену сообщества `stackoverflow`?)

Comment: @AndreiKhotko: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло. Не обижусь, что вы!